# Maintaining Order of a Pandas Multiindex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lvl0 = ['foo', 'bar']
lvl1 = ['x', 'y']

cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([lvl0, lvl1])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,4), columns=cols)
```

Which produces:

```
    foo                     bar
    x           y           x           y
0   0.885461    0.613618    0.404915    0.855922
1   0.096102    0.161894    0.786328    0.805401
2   0.035256    0.476391    0.834996    0.826073
```

I want to add another column, but when I do it gets placed at the end:

df[('foo', 'z')] = np.random.rand(3)

```
    foo                     bar                     foo
    x           y           x           y           z
0   0.885461    0.613618    0.404915    0.855922    0.782947
1   0.096102    0.161894    0.786328    0.805401    0.898574
2   0.035256    0.476391    0.834996    0.826073    0.407470
```

whereas I want it to visually group by the lvl0 column, like this:

```
    foo                                 bar
    x           y           z           x           y
0   0.885461    0.613618    0.782947    0.404915    0.855922
1   0.096102    0.161894    0.898574    0.786328    0.805401
2   0.035256    0.476391    0.407470    0.834996    0.826073
```

What is the best way to do this?  I've thought about inspecting df.columns beforehand, making a list of the lvl0 column names as they were, and then reassigning df afterwards like:

```
old_col_order = some_sort_of_columns_gymnastics()
df = df[old_col_order]
```

But these seemed messy and I can't be the first person to want new columns to be ordered.  I also considered using sort_index, but my original order is not in lexicographical order either, so I'd still have to find the original order somehow.

Comment: Use `sort_index`: `df = df.sort_index(level=0, axis=1)`

Comment: This works if I want them in lexigraphical order, but I'd like to maintain the original (non-lexigraphical) order

Comment: You definitely want Max's answer in that case. Do mark it accepted if it helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [215]: new_pos = df.columns.get_loc(('foo','y')) + 1

In [216]: df.insert(new_pos, ('foo','z'), np.random.rand(3))

In [217]: df
Out[217]:
        foo                           bar
          x         y         z         x         y
0  0.368823  0.820497  0.192941  0.174843  0.060076
1  0.111381  0.986995  0.163618  0.517629  0.836983
2  0.431267  0.058645  0.223167  0.793508  0.936183
```

alternatively if we don't know the last sub-column (`y` in our case):

```
In [250]: df.insert(len(df.columns.to_series().loc['foo']), ('foo','z'), np.random.rand(3))

In [251]: df
Out[251]:
        foo                           bar
          x         y         z         x         y
0  0.368823  0.820497  0.294450  0.174843  0.060076
1  0.111381  0.986995  0.521423  0.517629  0.836983
2  0.431267  0.058645  0.264008  0.793508  0.936183
```

Demo - let's add a `z` sub-column to `bar` column:

```
In [292]: x
Out[292]:
        foo                 bar                 baz
          x         y         x         y         x         y
0  0.368823  0.820497  0.174843  0.060076  0.368823  0.820497
1  0.111381  0.986995  0.517629  0.836983  0.111381  0.986995
2  0.431267  0.058645  0.793508  0.936183  0.431267  0.058645

In [293]: last_subcol = x.columns.to_series().loc['bar'].index[-1]

In [294]: last_subcol
Out[294]: 'y'

In [295]: new_pos = df.columns.get_loc(('bar',last_subcol)) + 1

In [296]: x.insert(new_pos, ('bar','z'), np.random.rand(3))

In [297]: x
Out[297]:
        foo                 bar                           baz
          x         y         x         y         z         x         y
0  0.368823  0.820497  0.174843  0.060076  0.694670  0.368823  0.820497
1  0.111381  0.986995  0.517629  0.836983  0.722398  0.111381  0.986995
2  0.431267  0.058645  0.793508  0.936183  0.126137  0.431267  0.058645
```

Comment: I was going to comment about not knowing the last sub-column, but you beat me to it.  The alternative proposed doesn't quite work though, as it assumes I want to insert into the first group.  I like the idea though, now working through how to refactor for any group

Comment: Feels a little ugly still, but I can use "last_subcol = df.loc[df.index[0], 'bar'].index[-1]" and "insert_loc = df.columns.get_loc(('bar', 'z'), np.random.rand(3))" and that ties things together

Comment: @Andrew, common! I just have finished __excatly__ the same solution 8-O I even used the same variable name: `last_subcol` :-D